# Adding hyperlinks to the Description field

Tags: plone

I am a user, not a programmer, whose forthcoming new website on Plone 4 requires adding hyperlinks inside the Description field of pages and folders. This is needed to point specific words to our website Dictionary as we had been doing on EZ Publish for the last 10 years.

Our developer says this can't be done in Plone. I'm looking to help them find how to do this (they don't seem to use English-language forums).

Is there an existing add-on or existing code for this? If not, is it possible to code this in? How? If not, will it become standard in Plone 5?

Comment: Is that "only links and everything else should still be filtered out", and "but we cannot expect our editors to reliably input `<a href=` style html into the desccription text field?

Comment: @downvoters: Please leave a note why you're downvoting and consider SO is also used of plone.org to give user-support, thanks.

Comment: It's not this way by default because the description field is a standard Dublin Core metadata field. Having it be plain text insures the text will be semantically meaningful. That doesn't mean you can't change it, but it does explain why it's done this way.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I just wanted to point that out, too. I think I've read lately (on the lists?), that major search-engines, aren't regarding it anymore, respectively filtering html of the keywords and weighting results  'correctly', but would need to verify.

Comment: Hi Ida. Search engine indexing and the purpose of DC metadata are not necessarily the same. Plone may be old fashioned in actually caring about DC metadata, but if we're ever to have a symantic web, somebody's got to care.

Comment: :-D Right, it might well be, that there are more cases for using the webz, than distributing kitten'n'chicken-pics. It's great you care, thanks a bunch! Nevermind fashions, they come and go. The "old-styles" are part of the reasons why ZOPE'n'Plone are still alive: Well thought concepts, standing the tests of time. Comparatively uber-mature, in my unhumble opinion.

Answer (score 3):

`<a href="http://python.org>Python</a>` will not work, as the description-field is ment and used as a meta-information of an item, holding plain-text only, and doesn't allow the usage of html-elements, nor embedded Javascript. That's probably why T. K. Nguyen recommends to provide an additional rich-text-field.

But you can use reStrucuredText instead. Tell your developer to exchange the description-snippet in concerned templates to:

```
<div tal:define="Std modules/Products.PythonScripts/standard;
                 restructured_text nocall: Std/restructured_text;"
    tal:content="structure python: restructured_text(context.Description())">
</div>
```

It will transform any word starting with 'http:' or 'https:' to a link, furthermore will also recognize mail-addresses like 'someone@plone.org' and transform them to mail-links (on click opens the user's default mail-client, if available, with the address pre-populated in the 'To'-field).

If you want to have named links, use the reStrucutredText-syntax for the input, like this:

```
`Check out Python`_, you'll love it.

`Write a mail`_ to someone.

.. _Python: http://www.python.org
.. _Write a mail: someone@example.org
```

The tricky part is to figure out, which templates are affected, but it's doable of my experience (did it with preserving line-breaks in listing-views, not reStructuredText).

Alternatively use a JS-workaround, as proposed by T. K. Nguyen. Be aware though, that it may break accessibility to some users.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to customize the description fields to be rich text (HTML) instead of plain text, but it requires a developer.

You can also use JavaScript to look at a description field and replace (for example) any string that starts with "http" with a hyperlink pointing to that URL. Your developer would have to look for examples of such JavaScript code and then would have to know how to register it on your site and then invoke it.

This describes how to do something similar, for PloneFormGen field help text (which is also plain text):

https://designinterventionsystems.com/blog/how-to-make-urls-clickable-in-ploneformgen-field-help-text

It might be easier to have your developer create a new rich-text description field and have all your content types include that new field. That, however, would require that you update the view templates for those modified content types. This is much easier with Dexterity, which ships with Plone 5 and is available for use with Plone 4.x.

Comment: Dear all,Thank you for your answers. Here are my comments back:
1. We need the hyperlink tool for INTERNAL links, ie to objects, not urls.
2. From a user point of view, this is a need, why not make Plone user-friendly here?

Comment: 3. This is standard on EZPublish, similar object-oriented build, since < 2005, when we built the site. Examples on just 1p of EZ to show you how frequent it is for us: www.graines-de-paix.org/fr/outils_de_paix/dictionnaire_pour_la_paix/%28offset%29/10.
We just migrated to Plone and these links need not only to remain but many more need to be created. 
 
So which of your solutions would best work for official launch and what could be planned for future release?
Thanks

Comment: 4. Our website is multi-lingual: will be in 10 languages. Translations are done online by volunteer translators. No html coding envisageable. It needs to be as easy as in the text body.

Comment: 5. This need is even greater for folders as they have no body in which to put the object hyperlinks.

Comment: @T. Kim Nguyen: Now, that he OP gave more details your answer applies again, upvoted. What do you think, in case regarding Dublin-Core has become useless, as the rumors go, would it be an enhancement, to pimp up the description, or better have one more field, like 'long-description'? (question goes to everybody actually)

Comment: @Grainesdepaix: The customizations which needed to be done are of a wider range, even if it will ever be considered to be a new "feature" in Plone one day, a developer will need to realize for you, if you need it now. The one thing to figure out, is whether a new field would be required or the description-field can be used, because regarding DublinCore is one of the reasons why Plone plays so remarkably well with search engines.

Comment: @Grainesdepaix: The example-link to the site you gave desn't work, gives me "Module non trouvé", typo? Concerning 5.) Could be solved without programming by clicking together a Dexterity-ContentType or using collections instead of folders, they have a text-field.

Comment: @Ida Ebkes +all
Thks for yr 3 answers. 
1. Link on EZ: the cleaned-up link is: www.graines-de-paix.org/fr/outils_de_paix/dictionnaire_pour_la_paix/(offset)/10.  ---
2. New long description field: I don't mind as long as it is displayed in lieu of the short description if this one is empty, and displayed in the list of pages inside a folder, Given referencing is key for us on these fields, is such a long description field affect our referencing?
5. Object hyperlinks in Folders: Thks, I'll check this with our developer. However, Aren't Collections rather complex for multiple translators ?

Comment: @IdaEbkes I think systematic research would be required, and since it would be a significant change it would likely have to be a PLIP with a lot of discussion. It does seem natural, from a user perspective, to have rich text description fields. Whatever we do won't be immediate, however, so Grainesdepaix will have to work with their developer to refine the requirement and adapt one of the suggested methods.

Comment: @T.KimNguyen: Thanks a a lot for your opinion. Actually I often witnessed users requesting this, but decision-makers never valued it high enough, to let it be realized, by now. I'm not up-to-date about the current state on how and where to open a PLIP (still on dev.plone.org?), but it could be worthwhile to have a public central space, where people looking for the same, can come together and join forces :-) Could you please guide us here, on how to proceed?

Comment: @Grainesdepaix: 2.) You're asking about a non-trivial migration-task, depending very much on the (here unknown) specifica of the current EZPublish-setup and is a littlle bit out of the scope of an SO-quest (we have many quests in one by now, as you might admit). No offense, but if your developer isn't able to solve this, you might want to get additional professional help.

Comment: @Grainesdepaix: 5.) The edit-mode-UI of an "old-style"-collection is actually identical with the one of an ordinary page ("Document"), so no change for your editors, here. Where the "new-style"-collections can bring you trouble, as unfortunately they break usability and accessibility in many ways. Creating a new collection, would require a little bit of advanced user-skills, that is: Set criteria on collection and set collection as default page of the folder.

Comment: @Grainesdepaix: SUMMARY: It'll be awesome to create an an addon on GitHub, realizing the additional 'long-description'-field. Chances are, you'll have other people joining to do that work. You'll likely get: valuable feedback (as here of T. K. Nguyen and S. McMahon), a testing user-base non-grata and it would be a great start for a PLIP (PLone Improvement Proposal). I wonder, if that wheel had been built already, seems like a lot of users want this.

Comment: @Ida Ebkes
Thks to all for your encouragement & ideas. 
**1. Migration**: we're doing the last bits manually.
**2. Collections**: can "old" collections still be used in a new CMS? If not, do translators need to get involved with new collections if within the text to be translated or can these be made invisible to them?
**3. PLIP & Github**: will ask our developer to do this, thanks! He's back on our project as of 14.9.
**4. Plone special support:** We accept proposals to help out on those points that the developers we use can't yet solve. We're truly satisfied with them otherwise.
Again thks!

Comment: Old-style collections are still available in Plone; you have to enable them via the Site Setup -> Types panel or check the box for "implicitly addable" in portal_types/Topic

Comment: @Grainesdepaix: You're very welcome, didn't mean to discourage you to ask more detailed quests, just feels to be the wrong place to do it in these comments. Give us a ping, if anything's public on Github! Best, Ida

Answer (score 2):

imho it's a really bad idea to convert the description field to any `richttext`  (html, rst, md) field. You need to change a hole bunch of templates to avoid html code rendered everywhere.

Example:

- search
- collections
- content
- portlets
- Addons

The description is also often used as `title` attribute on links, in those cases you need to convert it to plain/text. And there are several more issues, where you could ran into.

As @T. Kim Nguyen wrote: Consider add a new textfield and show it, where necessary, probably implemented as a [Viewlet](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/viewlets.html) in the below title slot.

Comment: Thanks for giving a list of some examples, which templates need to be regarded, as mentioned by Nguyen and me, already.
I came up with the reStructuredText-variant, to avoid the need to apply a richtext-editor like TinyMCE, and that would also work perfectly fine, if links aren't named, but by now the new comments of the OP revealed that a richtext-widget, is wanted.
To use a viewlet would be a really bad idea imho, because it'll not be a CT's field, anymore; not part of the item's form.
Tooltips could be customized also, e.g. with JQ-UI, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your current site, it seems like you want this to provide a teaser for each article, which may contain links.  If that is the case, then you can find other ways to do this without making the description html.

For instance, if you used [collective.cover](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.cover) for your portal/collection pages then a [Rich Text Tile](https://github.com/collective/collective.cover/blob/master/docs/end-user.rst#rich-text) would allow you to cut down the the object text to an appropriate size, but still edit it with a Rich Text editor, and keep/insert hyperlinks.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer seems appropriate. I've given the link to this page f Q and As to our developer who comes back on the 14th of Sept. He'll liaise from then on directly on this forum and let us know if this solution works.

Comment: @Grainesdepaix glad to hear - don't be scared to upvote!